# SQL: Complex Deletion

Tags: sql, count, hsqldb

I basically created some tables to play around with:  I have Two main tables, and a Many-Many join table.  Here is the DDL:  (I am using HSQLDB)

```
CREATE TABLE PERSON
(
    PERSON_ID INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, 
    NAME VARCHAR(50), MAIN_PERSON_ID INTEGER
)

CREATE TABLE JOB
(
    JOB_ID INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, 
    NAME VARCHAR(50)
)
CREATE TABLE JOB_PERSON
(
    PERSON_ID INTEGER, 
    JOB_ID INTEGER
)
ALTER TABLE JOB_PERSON ADD 
    CONSTRAINT FK_PERSON_JOB FOREIGN KEY(PERSON_ID) 
    REFERENCES PERSON ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE 

ALTER TABLE JOB_PERSON ADD
    CONSTRAINT FK_JOB_PERSON FOREIGN KEY(JOB_ID) 
    REFERENCES JOB ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE

ALTER TABLE PERSON ADD
    CONSTRAINT FK_PERSON_PERSON FOREIGN KEY(MAIN_PERSON_ID) 
    REFERENCES PERSON ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE

insert into person values(null,'Arthur', null);
insert into person values(null,'James',0);
insert into job values(null, 'Programmer')
insert into job values(null, 'Manager')
insert into job_person values(0,0);
insert into job_person values(0,1);
insert into job_person values(1,1);
```

I want to create a delete statement that deletes orphans from JOB (if there exists only one entry in the join table for a specific job) based on the PERSON.PERSON_ID.

In pseudo language:

```
delete from job where job_person.job_id=job.job_id 
AND count(job_person.job_id)=1 AND job_person.person_id=X
```

Where X is some person_id.  I have tried a lot of different ways; I think it is the "COUNT" part that is causing problems.  I am an SQL rookie, so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on the question. Orphans in the job table would have no corresponding entry in the job_person table.

Comment: According to Dave i don't understand why you are try to delete data which are used by an other table...

Comment: This is the functionality I was looking for:

DELETE FROM JOB
WHERE JOB_ID NOT IN (
    SELECT JOB_ID
    FROM JOB_PERSON
)

Comment: Aha. You should choose an answer @Cade Roux's is the most thorough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not following.

You cannot delete `JOB` rows which have `JOB_PERSON` rows (even one) because of your FK contraints.  Thus there is no way to delete `JOB` rows based on `PERSON` rows.

`JOB_PERSON` rows have to be deleted before either a `JOB` or `PERSON` can be deleted.

If you want to delete all `JOB` rows with no `JOB_PERSON`, then one way is:

```
DELETE FROM JOB
WHERE JOB_ID NOT IN (
    SELECT JOB_ID
    FROM JOB_PERSON
)
```

If you want to delete all `JOB_PERSON` rows for a particular person and then all orphans, do it in two steps:

```
DELETE FROM JOB_PERSON
WHERE PERSON_ID = X

DELETE FROM JOB
WHERE JOB_ID NOT IN (
    SELECT JOB_ID
    FROM JOB_PERSON
)
```

If you want to delete only the orphan `JOB`s previously linked to X, you will need to hold those in a temporary table before the first delete.

```
INSERT INTO TEMP_TABLE
SELECT JOB.JOB_ID
FROM JOB
INNER JOIN JOB_PERSON
    ON JOB_PERSON.JOB_ID = JOB.JOB_ID
WHERE JOB_PERSON.PERSON_ID = X

DELETE FROM PERSON
WHERE PERSON_ID = X

-- YOUR CASCADING DELETE DOES THIS:
/*
DELETE FROM JOB_PERSON
WHERE PERSON_ID = X
*/

-- Now clean up (only) new orphans on the other side
DELETE FROM JOB
WHERE JOB_ID NOT IN (
    SELECT JOB_ID
    FROM JOB_PERSON
)
AND JOB_ID IN (
    SELECT JOB_ID
    FROM TEMP_TABLE
)
```

Comment: "JOB_PERSON rows have to be deleted before either a JOB or PERSON can be deleted." - not when ON DELETE CASCADE has been used, as it has here.

Comment: Right, he's going to leave orphans one way or another.  I'll update the code.

Answer (score 1):

This will delete from your table JOB entries which have no entry in the table JOB_PERSON (Orpheans).

```
DELETE FROM JOB
WHERE JOB_ID NOT IN (
    SELECT JOB_ID
    FROM JOB_PERSON
)
```

You can't delete rows which are linked by a foreign on an other table...